# How can I change the color of this active nav-tab?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to change the colour in a natab when is active. I'm using Bootstrap 4.1.3.

I would like to see the orange tab when is active (clicked) and the other one White (like now). How can I do it in CSS? I have seen a lot of questions in Stackoverflow but any of them has helped me.

The code is the following:
HTML:

```
<div class="container" align="center">
<nav>
    <div class="nav nav-tabs nav-fill nav-test" role="tablist">
        <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-proxims-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-proxims" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-proxims" aria-selected="true">Pròxims</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-historic-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-historic" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-historic" aria-selected="false">Històric</a>
    </div>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
.nav-diables {
    color: Black;
    background-color: White;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.nav-diables > li.active {
    color: White;
    background-color: #FF7400 !important;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Kind regards,
Miquel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This code will solve your problem.**

```css
.nav-item {
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight: bold;
}
a.nav-item.nav-link.active {
    color: white;
    background-color: #f90;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container" align="center">
<nav class="nav nav-pills nav-justified" role="tablist">
        <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-proxims-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-proxims" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-proxims" aria-selected="true">Pròxims</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-historic-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-historic" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-historic" aria-selected="false">Històric</a>
</nav>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. I have not used pills, but with tabs is working. Thanks a lot, I just needed the "a.nav-item.active...". Resolved, thanks!